# multiple language support python

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, gettext

I want to change languages on some context but it doesn't get changed until I switch off the device and then switch it on.

the function written by me:

```
def LanguageChange(language_t):

    language_notation = language_t.split('-')[0]

    try:

        lang = gettext.translation('abc','/home/pi/abc/locale',
               languages=[language_notation])

    except e:
        lang = gettext.translation('abc','/home/pi/abc/locale',
               fallback = True,)

    lang.install()
```

when I call this function in another module it doesnot change the language when already running. But when i restart the code then langauge change occurs which i have selected

Comment: Seems to me, your `gettext.tranlation`  in the exception is missing a `s`

Comment: I've edited your question to add some hopefully relevant tags. I'm not sure I've got them right though, since your question omits a lot of important context, so please double check and edit it yourself if I've got anything wrong.